# Specifying model relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What is the point or benefits of specifying a relationship between one model to the other. For example, the laravel php framework has the methods hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo, etc... 
What are their basic functions and what are the consequences if you ignore such functions?
I am just a beginner in laravel and looking to expand my knowledge. Please don't crucify me for asking such a simple question. I have done the research but couldn't quite understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's built-in model expands from concept called [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (Object Relational Mapping), which basically maps a class directly to table in your database.

Database tables, are connected based on relationship, such as one record in `Order` belongs to one `Customer`, and one `Customer` may have many `Order`s. These relations can be defined in Eloquent using the relationship methods (`hasOne`, `hasMany`, etc.) to tell Eloquent how to query other tables so you don't have to manually query them.

To illustrate.

> Give me all orders created by our customer John (Customer ID: 1001)

```
// Using QueryBuilder
$orders = Order::where('customer_id', 1001)->get();

// Using Eloquent
// Assuming relationship has been defined
$orders = Customer::findOrFail(1001)->orders;
```

> **Slightly more complicated case:** 
>       Give me all items contained in all orders created by John.

```
// Using QueryBuilder
$orders = Order::where('customer_id', 1001)->get();
$orderIDs = array_pluck('id', $orders->toArray());
$items = Item::whereIn('order_id', $orderIDs)->get();

// Eloquent
$items = Customer::findOrFail(1001)->orders->items;
```

As you can see by defining the relationship you are freeing yourself from manually querying each related record. However it is important to know that there may be cases where you want to use QueryBuilder to manually querying entries when speed/performance may be a concern.